# jQuery nested span text value

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="divBase0" class="divBase">
<span id="p0" class="displayText">text line 1</span>
<span id="l0" class="displayText">text line 2</span>
<span id="f0" class="displayText">text line 3</span>
<span id="d0" class="displayText">text line 4</span>
<span id="t0" class="displayText">text line 5</span>
</div>
```

I have the above div and spans in my page.  In the following code I am able to get the id of p0 (alert(pID).  However I really want to get the text inside the span of p0.

```
$("div[id^='divBase']").live("click", function () {
    var pID = $(this).find("span[id^='p']").attr("id");
    alert(pID);
});
```

I should note that I'm generating the divs and the spans (writing them out in jQuery) when the form loads.  So that is why I have the .live.    Am I doing it the best way to find the nested span(s) in the divBase0?  And secondly how can I get the text in span p0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to get the text inside, like this:

```
$("div.divBase").live("click", function () {
    var pText = $(this).find("span[id^='p']").text();
    alert(pText);
});
```

Is this the best way?  If you need the IDs then sure, if not then just use classes, like this:

```
<div class="divBase">
  <span class="p displayText">text line 1</span>
  <span class="l displayText">text line 2</span>
  <span class="f displayText">text line 3</span>
  <span class="d displayText">text line 4</span>
  <span class="t displayText">text line 5</span>
</div>
```

And use classes in your functions:

```
$("div.divBase").live("click", function () {
    alert($(this).find("span.p").text());
});
```

One step better would be attaching the handler to the parent element all these `.divBase` elements are in with [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), like this:

```
$("#divContainer").delegate("div.divBase", "click", function () {
    alert($(this).find("span.p").text());
});
```

This eliminates the initial selector performance cost as well as being cheaper or future clicks.