# How can I change span text inside another span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a collapsible list that changes from a '+' to a '-' and back depending upon whether the list is collapsed or expanded.  I can get to the text using this statement:

```
$(this).children().eq(i).children('span')[0].firstChild.outerText;
```

But I cannot figure out how to change the value.  There's probably a more elegant solution that a JQuery Guru can show me.  Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pdlarue/v494vzdc/).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4111149/1735836) is the closest answer I could find to my question but I don't know how to implement it or even if there is a better way.

Comment: You can use a combo of a class and pseudo-element `::before`.

Comment: Your jQuery is completely off. You cannot rely in event target from a far ancestor element. One day you'll add another element child and your script will break.

Comment: Also `$(this).children;` look at the jQuery docs. Should be `.children()` ... so many errors that your text issue is the least problem here... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// Make your code clean and readable!
// Don't target #test. Go directly for your "title/heading" elements ("buttons")
$(".Collapsable").on("click", function() {

  // Who is my +/- icon element?
  var $ico = $(this).find(".symbol");
  // Traverse up to LI and than back down to find my UL sub list:
  var $subList = $(this).closest("li").find("> ul");
  // Realize the current collapsed/expanded state
  var isSubListHidden = $subList.is(":hidden");

  // OK, time to rock!
  // Change teh text +/-
  $ico.text(isSubListHidden ? "-" : "+");
  
  // Toggle sub lists:
  $subList.stop().slideToggle();

});
```

```css
.hideUnorderedList {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul id="test">
    <li id="first">
      <span class="Collapsable"><span class="symbol">+</span>First One</span>
      <ul id="myfirstlist" class="hideUnorderedList">
        <li>Something to do</li>
        <li>Something else to do</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="second">
      <span class="Collapsable"><span class="symbol">+</span>Second One</span>
      <ul id="mysecondlist" class="hideUnorderedList">
        <li>Second thing to do</li>
        <li>Second other thing to do</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be simplified quite a bit. Rather than trying to match index, just use jQuery's [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method to target descendants:

```js
$('#test > li').click(function() {
  var $symbol = $(this).find('.symbol');
  $(this).find('ul').slideToggle('fast');
  if ($symbol.text() === ' +') {
    $symbol.text(' -');
  } else {
    $symbol.text(' +');
  }
});
```

```css
.hideUnorderedList {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul id="test">
    <li id="first">
      <span class="Collapsable"><span class="symbol"> +</span>First One</span>
      <ul id="myfirstlist" class="hideUnorderedList">
        <li>Something to do</li>
        <li>Something else to do</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="second">
      <span class="Collapsable"><span class="symbol"> +</span>Second One</span>
      <ul id="mysecondlist" class="hideUnorderedList">
        <li>Second thing to do</li>
        <li>Second other thing to do</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `.find('.symbol')` three times? Cache.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan better? ;P

Comment: Symbol text can further be simplified as : $symbol.text( $symbol.text() === ' +' ? ' -' : ' +')

Comment: Nom it's not better because you are targeting any LI,... :P

Comment: WOW!!!!!  I knew what I had was ugly!  In case nobody could tell, I'm a newbie with JQuery.  But all my crappy code has been transformed to only three lines of code.  Thank you for showing me a better way!  :-)